# Get MacOS notification text programmatically

Tags: macos, applescript, notifications

This applescript used to work to get the contents of a MacOS notification:

```
    get value of ¬
        static text of ¬
        scroll area 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        process "NotificationCenter"
```

This has since stopped working since Ventura(?). My question is this: Is there any way to get the contents of a MacOS notification programmatically? Either through applescript, accessibility options, python, swift, or perhaps even introducing a tweak to the Mac OS operating system(this is purely for personal use, not for distribution).

I'd really appreciate ideas! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `NotificationCenter` application instead of the `System Events`.

Basically, the following AppleScript retrieves the list of notifications in the Notification Center. Then, it checks if there are any notifications there, and, if there's at least one, it retrieves the title, subtitle and informative text of the notification at the top of the stack (most recent) and displays them in form of an alert. It will repeat this step with every notification in the Notification Center.

```
tell application "NotificationCenter"
    set notificationsList to (get notifications of current application)
    if (count of notificationsList) > 0 then
        repeat with aNotification in notificationsList
            set notificationTitle to title of aNotification
            set notificationSubtitle to subtitle of aNotification
            set notificationText to informativeText of aNotification
            display alert "Notification title: " & notificationTitle & return & "Notification subtitle: " & notificationSubtitle & return & "Notification text: " & notificationText
        end repeat
    else
        display alert "No notifications"
    end if
end tell
```

You should get an alert with notification titles, subtitles and informative texts of all notifications in your Notification Center.

Comment: thanks for the script. Having some trouble making it work. It's saying "the variable notifications is not defined"

* made a small change - changed "informative text" to "informativeText" to resolve a syntax error.

Comment: @ctoday1 Thanks for pointing this out. Indeed, there was a syntax error with `informative text`. I also fixed the error with `notifications` by adding `of current application`, which is the Notification Center and therefore will not alter the intent of the script. :)

Comment: Interesting.  Is it possible this is [AI generated content](https://i.imgur.com/uGUVNXx.jpg) and it was never tested resulting in that syntax error not being caught?

Comment: @Thinkr Thanks for the revision. Getting a new error with this one however: "Can’t make notifications into type reference".

Comment: @ctoday1 Yes. The `notifications` property of the Notification Center will actually return a list of references instead of a list of objects. I fixed this in the script. Also, having a dialog in a `repeat` could cause errors since dialogs may not support special characters. Just changed that to `display alert` to be sure. :)

Comment: You can't expect people to debug your answers for you. Haven't you tried this on your Mac before posting?

Comment: @nohillside I have on my old Mac which is running macOS Big Sur. I cannot currently try on my newer Mac running Ventura (for reasons I won't state). This worked on Big Sur.

Comment: The question is specifically about Ventura, actually.

Comment: @nohillside Yes. I know this. This is why I am trying to solve the OP's problems without having the ability to test the script on Ventura. This seems to be working on Ventura too (just some errors to fix).

Comment: @Thinkr thanks for the further revision. However, still getting this error on ventura:
error "Can’t make notifications into type reference."
I wonder if Ventura changed how this stuff is handled. I know stuff like this used to work on earlier OS versions.

Comment: @ctoday1 This is probably the case. I think there is another way of doing what you want to do with the NSUserNotificationCenter class from AppleScriptObjC. I'm currently trying to make a script for that. I'll edit the answer with I it when finished. ;)